# getting javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder exception on posting json to webservice

Tags: web-services, maven

While posting Json from web client I am getting "Internal server error(500)" on web console log and on server console log I am getting 
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jersey-serlvet] in context with path [/AlpagoREST] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;

My web client code is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){

        var url='http://localhost:8080/AlpagoREST/rest/json/metallica/post2';   
        inputString1 ='{"location":"Location_trial"}';
        alert(url);
        alert(inputString1);

        $.postJSON = function(url, inputString1, callback) {
            alert("reached here");
            return jQuery.ajax({
            headers: { 
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' 
            },
            'type': 'POST',
            'url': url,
          'data': inputString1,
            'dataType': 'json',
            'success': callback
            });
        };

        $.postJSON(url, inputString1, function(data) {
            console.log("Done posting");
        });

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

My Server side web service is as below:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/post2")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response trial(Trial_JSON tjson) {
   System.out.println("reached here in post for Tjson");

   System.out.println("Office Location="+tjson.getLocation());

   String result="Mission done it looks";
        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();


    }
```

and my Pom depencies are as below:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>


<!--  Appended for integration-->
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>

                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!--Added further  -->
        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.18</version>
        </dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>1.18</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>  
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>  
        <version>1.9.5</version>  
    </dependency> 
    <!-- For Jeresey Test Framework -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.9</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-external</artifactId>
          <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- For AOP -->
<!-- Spring AOP + AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--   Adding for Media type   -->

 <dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
<version>2.7</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
<version>2.7</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
<version>2.7</version>
 </dependency>

 <!--  -->
  <dependency> 
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId> 
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId> 
            <version>1.1.1</version> 
        </dependency>
```

Comment: You need to decide on what major Jersey version you are going to use, either 1.x and 2.x. After you make this decision get rid of the other dependencies. If you do with 1.x, I see you have four different version dependencies. Stick with one version and change the rest accordingly. And get rid of jsr311. It will get pulled in depending on what Jersey version you will go with

Comment: thanks it worked.I removed following dependencies from my pom  :- <dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
<version>2.7</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
<version>2.7</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
<version>2.7</version>
 </dependency>